# Why isn't a callable callable within a Python with block?

Tags: python, with-statement, callable

Any rhyme or reason as to why a callable isn't callable within a Python 3.5 `with` statement?

```
class Seriously(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Enter " + self.name)

    def __call__(self):
        print("Call " + self.name)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("Exit " + self.name)

a = Seriously('a')
a.__enter__()
a()
a.__enter__()

with Seriously('b') as b:
    b()
```

seriously produces

```
Enter a
Call a
Enter a
Enter b
Exit b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-91a5d11e1b2e> in <module>()
     18 
     19 with Seriously('b') as b:
---> 20     b()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am I missing in [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not return anything from the `__enter__` method, which gets translated by the python compiler into a return of `None`. You are supposed to return the value to be bound by the `as` clause from `__enter__`.

The `with` statement is desugared as

```
mgr = (EXPR)
exit = type(mgr).__exit__ 
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)  ### <--- usually the same as mgr.__enter__()
exc = True
try:
    try:
        VAR = value               ### <--- value returned by __enter__, VAR from with/as statement
        BLOCK
    except:
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
                raise
finally:
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

(from the PEP you linked to in the question).

Comment: `return self` at the end of __call__ did it.  Will accept once able, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `__enter__` method could return the object (`self`) explicitly, the constructor has already been called before `__enter__`.  You could just pass the object through or alter it or return a different object.

The `__exit__` method gets four arguments, `self`, followed by an exception type , value, and a traceback object – the same as returned by `sys.exc_info()`.   If there has not been an exception, then the three exception parameters are all `None`.

If `__exit__` returns `True` this indicates that the exception has been handled and is not propagated.  A return value of `False` indicates there has not been an exception.

Comment: It is not a mandate to return `self` from `__enter__`. It depends on the requirement

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri:  yes, I should have said *could* instead of *should*.  I say "You could just pass the object through or alter it or return a different object".

Comment: I think *should* was fine as it is mandatory(isn't? None is of no use with `with`) to return some object, but it was not worthy to mention about `self` at the very start of this answer. You may mention about `self` as a suggestion later in the answer since it suits OPs requirement. PS: Just my thought :)